# awk print conditions

Tags: awk

Trying to print lines with a condition, example -

input example

```
Hello:world
Hello:worlds:
Hello:world:example
```

attempt -

```
awk -F":" print $1 " + " $2 && if($3 != "") { " + " $3 }
```

so expected output would be

```
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

Comment: A little more prose would make sense.

Comment: Is it only the 3rd field that could possibly be empty, or do you want to delete all empty fields?

Comment: You have other issues with your code but the big, glaring one is: tools that interpret scripts (awk, sed perl, rub, etc.) require you to provide the scribt within quotes (single or double) or in a file or some other clearly delimited way. You can't just write `awk script`, you have to write `awk 'script'` or `awk -f scriptfile`.

Answer (score 6):

If you only have to care about an empty *last* field, then using `sed` would be shorter:

```
$ sed 's/:$//; s/:/ + /g' file
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

---

Your attempted `awk` command can be salvaged like this:

```
$ awk -F":" '{ print $1 " + " $2 ($3 != "" ? " + " $3 : "") }' file
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

Or, by using `OFS` (the output field delimiter):

```
$ awk -F":" -v OFS=' + ' '{ print $1, $2 ($3 != "" ? OFS $3 : "") }' file
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

Additionally getting rid of the negative test:

```
$ awk -F":" -v OFS=' + ' '{ print $1, $2 ($3 == "" ? "" : OFS $3 ) }' file
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

Answer (score 5):

If last column is empty, remove last column from output. `$1=$1` forces awk to recreate the row with the output field separator (OFS).

```
awk '$NF=="" {NF--} {$1=$1}1' FS=':' OFS=' + ' file
```

Output:

```
Hello + world
Hello + worlds
Hello + world + example
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Note that the effect of decrementing `NF` is undefined in the POSIX standard. It may work in some implementations of `awk`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thank you for pointing that out. I used GNU awk.